# Multisite sub-site dashboard redirects to /wp-admin/

Tags: multisite, dashboard

I have successfully set up WordPress Multisite on a linux server. I'm able to add sites using Super Admin.

When I go to Dashboard > Sites, I see the following:

**Site 1** - The main Multisite website

**Site 2** - A site I have recently added

When I select "Dashboard" for Site 2, I am redirected to the dashboard for Site 1. To visit the dashboard on Site 2, I have to visit http://site2.mydomain.com/wp-admin via my browser. I'm a little baffled to why this is happening.

Wildcard DNS is switched on for the domain. Here's the .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache and tried jumping in from a different browser?

Comment: Seems to be happening with a cleared cache and in other browsers too.

Comment: What's the URL that appears in the network dropdown for Site 2's dashboard? Does it match the one you use to go to it directly?

Comment: Hey @PatJ. Yes, the Site 2 dashboard URL matches the Site 1 dashboard URL i.e. http://domain.com/wp-admin.