# Using multisite, how can I get two different sites on the network to have different active themes?

Tags: multisite, directory

I'm having some trouble getting multisite to work as expected. I have followed a few tutorials and have done everything step by step. Multisite is enabled, and I'm able to access the network of sites, however when I change a theme on one site's dashboard, it changes for all of my sites.

I'm using sub-directories, so I have `mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com/site1` etc. I've noticed when I go to the dashboard for `mydomain.com/site1`, it just takes me to `mydomain.com/wp-admin/`. I don't know if this is expected behavior but I thought it might be `mydomain.com/site1/wp-admin/`. It seems like the routing isn't working properly.

I made sure to follow the directions of overwriting the entire .htaccess file with the code provided after enabling multisite.

Either way, it doesn't look like there's any difference between my two site's dashboards, so when I change one theme it is changing the other.

Am I missing something? Or what should I do to troubleshoot this?

Here is my entire `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The bottom part of `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
//define( 'WP_CACHE', true );
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/gd-config.php' );
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct');
define('FS_CHMOD_DIR', (0705 & ~ umask()));
define('FS_CHMOD_FILE', (0604 & ~ umask()));

define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', 'false');
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mydomain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

One more thing to note, when I go to network admin -> all sites, and click "edit" on `mydomain.com/site1`, its "Site Address" is set correctly, but in the "Settings" tab both Siteurl and Home are set to `mydomain.com`, it seems as if I can't change those. When I save they revert back.

Comment: There absolutely need to be different dashboards as you said: mydomain.com/site1/wp-admin/. On the mydomain.com/wp-admin/ you are just changing  the theme of main site. Seems like for some reason you are redirected to the main site dashboard. Maybe some code in the htaccess or something wrong in the wp-config.php. We need to see them. But do not show the keys and password in the wp-config.php.

Comment: I updated the question with the files. I also noticed its similar to this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143805/multisite-sub-site-dashboard-redirects-to-wp-admin?rq=1. However even if I force this in the URL: `mydomain.com/site1/wp-admin/` it redirects me to `mydomain.com/wp-admin/`.

Comment: Starting to think it's because of my web host now because those home/siteurl settings won't change for the sub-site. I will check with them.

Comment: The htaccess looks fine. The wp-config.php has some weird things, I don't know what is the gd-config.php for, first time I see this. And then there are the FS_ ones, which usually are not used too. But maybe it is something for your hosting. Also the 'false' for the SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL has to be without quotes, like the true. And a question for you is, are you using cloudflare or https? I have heard some redirection problems related to those things.

Comment: I updated to `false`. I'm not using cloudflare or https just because it's a new domain and I haven't set up SSL yet. I'm assuming those unidentified lines are from GoDaddy since it's "Manage WordPress Hosting"; I think I'm reading that multisite is only eligible on standard hosting.

Comment: If it is managed, then probably they have done some customizations that cause this issue. Ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the web host. GoDaddy Managed WordPress hosting [does not work](https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managed-WordPress-Hosting/WP-Multisite-available-under-Godaddy-Managed-WordPress/m-p/10643#U10643) with multisite. I contacted them and got it switched over to their cPanel standard hosting and it's working great now.

Thanks for the help.